# A feature to aggregate my favorite Stack Exchange sites into one feed

Tags: feature-request

As a full stack developer, I love the Stack Overflow and WordPress Development sites in equal measure.

Is there a more efficient way that I can keep tabs on my favorite sites by aggregating the two sites into one feed?

Comment: What exactly you want to see?  Questions? Answers? Based on tags?

Comment: May be [this](https://www.lifewire.com/rss-aggregator-tools-3486469) helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an RSS reader.

At the bottom of the home page of each site is a link to an RSS feed of recent questions...

[image: Screenshot of RSS link]

Using an RSS reader you can aggregate all the pages that interest you.

You don't get a live second-by-second update, but you do get to see all the questions a little after they come in.

Other pages also have RSS feeds, follow what you need.